# How to make caption width of a table equal to the width of a table?

Tags: tables, floats, formatting, pdftex, captions

I have a caption inside of a box with a background color. My problem is I need to align the width of the box to equal the table width.

> Current output

[image]

[image]

> My code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,graphicx,xcolor,caption,tabulary}

\newcommand{\captionbackgroundcolor}[1]{\colorlet{cpbgcol}{#1}}
\DeclareCaptionFont{white}{\color{white}}
\captionbackgroundcolor{black!50}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{overlay}{\colorbox{cpbgcol}{#1#2#3}}
\captionsetup{format=overlay,font=white}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{table*}[!htbp]
\caption{{Categor\'{\i}as y variables de la primera muestra} }
\label{tw-592d6b646c21}
\def\arraystretch{1.2} 
\ignorespaces 
\centering 
\begin{tabulary}{\linewidth}{|L|L|}
\hline 
samlple &sample\\

sample & sample\\
\hline 
\end{tabulary}\par
\end{table*}



\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Comment: In the second picture, the caption was placed inside the tabular using \multicolumn, and the width was set  arbitrarily.  At least, the width of the first column seems to have nothing to do with the content.

Answer (score 1):

I've modified few of your tags, please check and confirm if this meets your requirement:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,caption,threeparttable,booktabs}
\newcommand{\captionbackgroundcolor}[1]{\colorlet{cpbgcol}{#1}}
\DeclareCaptionFont{white}{\color{white}}
\captionbackgroundcolor{black!50}
%\DeclareCaptionFormat{overlay}{\colorbox{cpbgcol}{#1#2#3}}
%\captionsetup{format=overlay,font=white}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\long\def\@tablecaption#1#2{\colorbox{black!10}{\vbox{\fontsize{9.5}{10}\selectfont%
{\bfseries #1}\hspace{1em}{#2\strut}\par}}
  \vspace{\belowcaptionskip}}
\def\table{\let\@makecaption\@tablecaption\@float{table}}
\let\endtable\end@float
\makeatother

   \begin{table}
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{This is example
table with width equal to default width in table environment}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
Col 1& Col 2 & Col 3 & Col 4 \\
\hline
1 &  2 &  3 &  4 \\
5 &  6 &  7 &  8 \\
9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}[flushleft]\footnotesize
\item[1] Long, long, long, long, long, long, note
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: output is wrong when I use the following code lines are breaking \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}

Comment: @Shalu Sorry, in your code, you are using \hline, and by mistake I was used \toprule, etc...Please confirm really you need to use \toprule...or \hline...

Comment: \hline is needed

Comment: Please check the updated answer...

Comment: caption width and table width is not same.

Answer (score 0):

Since captions normally fill the whole page width, the best way to put a caption inside a box is to use a minipage (or modify `\@makecaption`).  Similarly, `\colorbox` does not wrap text, so you need a `\parbox` inside.

Note that `\colorbox` adds a `\fboxsep` gap on all sides.  `\tabulary` adds a `\tabcolsep` gap to the sides of each column cell.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,graphicx,xcolor,caption,tabulary}

\newcommand{\captionbackgroundcolor}[1]{\colorlet{cpbgcol}{#1}}
\DeclareCaptionFont{white}{\color{white}}
\captionbackgroundcolor{black!50}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{overlay}{\colorbox{cpbgcol}{\parbox{\dimexpr \textwidth-2\fboxsep}%
  {\centering#1#2#3}}}
\captionsetup{format=overlay,font=white}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{table*}[!htbp]
\centering 
\def\arraystretch{1.2}%
\begin{tabulary}{\linewidth}{|L|L|}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\begin{minipage}{2in}% arbitrary width
  \abovecaptionskip=\tabcolsep
  \belowcaptionskip=\tabcolsep
  \caption{Categor\'{\i}as y variables de la primera muestra}%
  \label{tw-592d6b646c21}%
\end{minipage}}\\
\hline 
samlple &sample\\
sample & sample\\
\hline 
\end{tabulary}
\par
\end{table*}

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]